# How to solve a quadratic matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, quadratic-variation

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\omega^H} \boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{\Theta^H} \boldsymbol{h_r} \boldsymbol{h_r^H} \boldsymbol{\Theta} \boldsymbol{G^H} \boldsymbol{\omega}=a\\
\boldsymbol{\omega^H} \boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{\Theta^H} \boldsymbol{H_e} \boldsymbol{H_e^H} \boldsymbol{\Theta} \boldsymbol{G^H} \boldsymbol{\omega}=b
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{\omega} \in C^{M \times 1}$, $\boldsymbol{G} \in C^{M \times N}$, $\boldsymbol{\Theta} \in C^{N \times N}$ is diagonal matrix, $\boldsymbol{h_r} \in C^{N \times 1}$, $\boldsymbol{H_e} \in C^{N \times t}$, $t \geq 1$. $\boldsymbol{G}, \boldsymbol{h_r}, \boldsymbol{H_e}, a, b$ are deterministic.

Can I express $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ as a funtion of $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$?

Comment: You have $M$ unknowns but only two equations so it seems highly unlikely unless $M=2$

Comment: The term "matrix equation" usually is reserved for equations whose unknown is a matrix.